# How in the code below create snake function automatically got triggered?

Tags: python, class

I created the snake class for a project in a course I am doing as below, `create_snake` and `move_snake` were its methods, then how did `create_snake` automatically got triggered when I called the class and not `move_snake`?

This was the `Snake` class created:

```
class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.segment = []      
        self.create_snake()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in START_POSITIONS:
            square = Turtle()
            square.penup()
            square.shape("square")
            square.color("white")
            square.goto(position)
            self.segment.append(square)  

    def move_snake(self):
        for seg in range(len(self.segment) - 1, 0, -1):
            newx = self.segment[seg - 1].xcor()
            newy = self.segment[seg - 1].ycor()
            self.segment[seg].goto(newx, newy)
        self.segment[0].forward(DISTANCE)
```

This was code when it got called:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import time
from Snake import Snake
screen=Screen()
snake=Snake()

game_is_on=True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update() 
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    snake.move_snake()
```

Why did I have to call `snake.move_snake()` here?

Comment: `create_snake` is automatically called because it's called from `__init__`. `move_snake` is not called from `__init__`.

Comment: but if I put move_snake in the init function, it didn't work. why was it?

Comment: Because you want to call `move_snake` every 0.1 seconds in a loop, not just once when creating the `Snake` instance.